# cd\ returns New line.?

Tags: command-line, bash

[image]

I want to go to `$` prompt? But how without having to [Enter] twice ?

`cd ..` works just fine and so does`cd /`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `\` character is considered an "escape" in the Bash shell.

Take the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install some-package some-other-package yet-another-package oh-my-we-have-a-lot-of-packages and-still-another-package wow-so-many-packages
```

We can instead rewrite this command like this:

```
sudo apt-get install some-package some-other-package \
yet-another-package oh-my-we-have-a-lot-of-packages \
and-still-another-package wow-so-many-packages
```

Bash will interpret the `\` to mean "read the next line as part of this one." In your case, you type `cd \`, so Bash expects you to give it another line.

If you want to go quickly back to your homedir (that is, `~`), you can either use `cd ~` *or* just plain `cd`.

Answer (score 4):

With `cd\` you have entered a `cd` command and the `\` tells the shell that you want to continue your command on a new line. So it gives you a new line.

With `cd` alone (without `\`) you would go to your home directory, `cd ..` brings you to the parent directory of the current one, and `cd /` to the base directory '/'.

Comment: `\` doesn't specifically imply newline. The `\` serves as an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), which modifies the meaning of whatever character/byte comes next. In this particular case it happened to be coming from Enter key, which normally means carriage return or `^M` character. With `\` that modifies into newline.  Similar example,  `echo "$HOME"` vs `echo \$HOME`, where `\` modifies meaning of `$` from signifying a variable to literal `$`

Comment: Oops, stackexchange formatting messed up the comment. I was saying "The \ doesn't specifically imply newline.